# Notification callback from tomcat when server is up

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

How to know when tomcat is fully up? Like in spring I have the DispatcherServlet.initFrameworkServlet(), which is called when application starts, is there any way to get notified when server is Up.

Answer (score 1):

You can know when your web app is deployed and ready to serve requests by implementing ServletContextListener, from what I understand it should suite your needs. An example

```
public class CustomContextListener
    implements ServletContextListener {

  private ServletContext context = null;

  public CustomContextListener() {}

  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)
  {
    // called when the app is undeployed
    this.context = null;
  }


  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
  {
    // called when the app is ready to service requests 
    this.context = event.getServletContext();
  }
}
```

you can place your logic in `contextInitialized` method and register a listener inside web.xml, by adding a listener element before the servlet definitions e.g.

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>
        your.package.CustomContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

---

For what concerns your question in the comment, **I want to know when tomcat has finished loading all the contexts/applications?** You can use the approach above, to have all the apps send a signal basically notifying that they're up and ready (e.g. store a while in a DB, send a request to an external server etc.)

If your intent is to control the order of deploy, e.g. deploy an app after all others are deployed, you should now that tomcat doesn't make any guarantees about the order of app deploy, they explain it in their [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q27)

> There is no expected startup order. Neither the Servlet spec nor Tomcat define  one. You can't rely on the apps starting in any particular order.
>
> While the above statement is certainly true, there is a potential
>   "workaround": If you actually have two (or more) apps depending on
>   each other, you may decide to start multiple services in you
>   server.xml:

```
<Service name="Webapps1">
  <Connector .../>

  <Engine ...>
     <Host appbase="webapps1" ...>
       ...        
     </Host>
  </Engine>
</Service>
<Service name="Webapps2">
  <Connector .../>

  <Engine ...>
     <Host appbase="webapps2" ...>
       ...        
     </Host>
  </Engine>
</Service>
```

> I.e. you split the regular "/webapps" directory into "/webapps1" and
>   "/webapps2", whereas everything in the former is deployed and started
>   before the later. The drawback is that you need separate ports for the
>   services.

Comment: thanks MasterSlave,
but my concern is about tomcat. I want to know when tomcat has finished loading all the contexts/applications.
please help

Comment: sorry, missed your comment, answered now for what is worth